# What is the 8 byte header/tag before the main ID3v2 header in .WAV files?

Tags: wav, chunks, id3, id3v2, riff

I am trying to implement some of the ID3v2.4 specification, e.g. some [documentation from here](https://mutagen-specs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/id3/id3v2.4.0-structure.html).

When editing the tags for some .WAV files via the software *Audacity* or *MP3tag*, inspecting the byte stream afterwards I can see there is actually a small tag before the main ID3 header and frame information.

It is an 8 byte sized header that appears to follow the format `id3 xx\0\0`, where `xx` is a 16 bit value in Little Endian format that seems to be the size information of the data from the main `ID3` header onwards and `\0\0` are two NULL bytes.

It may be that the two NULL bytes are actually part of the total size information as well, but I haven't attempted to write that much data to check that. It may be that it is a 4 byte size value like in the main ID3 header, but I would like to confirm this.

I cannot see a mention of this in the spec, is this part of another spec? Deleting this 8 byte header will result in *Audacity* and *MP3tag* not understanding the tag anymore.

*Audacity* version: 3.2.4 (this actually writes ID3v2.3 tags); *MP3tag* version: 3.19.

Comment: Almost the first thing in the linked documentation is [the header and what its fields are](https://mutagen-specs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/id3/id3v2.4.0-structure.html#id3v2-header). Is it not that header you're seeing?

Comment: Apologies, when I posted the question, I put the wrong information. It should have said 8-bytes, not 10-bytes. The 10-byte header is well documented. The section I am referring to is an 8-byte header. And it starts with lowercase id3, not ID3.

Comment: So a header before the header? Then it seems like a part of the WAV file. To be more precise, a [RIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format) chunk.

Comment: That seems to be closely linked to what I'm seeing, I will have a further read.

Comment: It seems to be this RIFF chunk you're referring to, although I can't get concrete examples for id3 specifically. It seems that from all the examples I have tried, it stays 8-bytes in length, and has no padding or a variable-sized field.

Comment: OK, now I understand...the variable sized field is the main id3 header and data I have been working with all this time. So this 8-byte header is part of this overall RIFF chunk. Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, it is amusing that my post is edited for grammar with a note saying 'Engrish'. Hyphens have been removed for <x>-byte/bit. Many official specifications use this format, and Microsoft Word actually suggests it. Perhaps AmigoJack should brush up on his Eng(r/l)ish.

Comment: Using a unit as [adjective](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/8-bit#Adjective) over the [noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bit#Noun_2) is indeed new to me. I discourage trusting suggestions from Microsoft products and welcome linked reasons. You overlooked that it was also [maybe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maybe#Adverb) vs. [may be](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maybe#Usage_notes). Also without [using @ in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) that user won't be notified of your comment (unless being the post author).